# Incorrect logo in Meta SE newsletter banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, newsletter

I don't know but this might be related to the new layout. On this meta site the newsletter form shows the Stack Overflow logo:

[image: Hate this site?]

Browser: Firefox 61 on Windows 10, no relevant plugins. The problem still occurs after a hard reload (AKA no caching).

This seems to be the fault of [this image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Img/unified/newsletter-ad.png?v=cd8f57b09e4a) being wrong.

Comment: The *example newsletter* link generates content based on MSE posts?

Comment: @rene yes, the example newsletter is fine and uses the correct styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *appears* to be fixed (as seen here on MSE), and while I have not manually checked all other network sites, it doesn't appear to be a problem for the network. Looks like it was a temporary glitch due to changes rolling out.

If it rears up again we'll poke more.

Comment: Yes, this shouldn't be a problem anymore as this component was migrated to the new Stacks layout

Comment: Hi @Tim I have seen yet an other problem, that I don't think is worth an own bug report. On some sites (esp. Worldbuilding) this new box is unreadable due to white font on bright background.